# .NET Core Console app: Read list of Azure storage blobs as read-only user

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have a problem, which I cannot figure out to solve:

Our company has appr. 20 Azure storage accounts with appr. 20 containers each. I want to write a .NET Core console application, which I can run on a (non-Azure) Windows server for backing up the blobs with read-only access to a (non-Azure) server.

If I would use the storage access keys, I would have the problems a) I would need 20 different access keys and b) the access keys allow for full access, which I don't want to grant this console application for security reasons. Using an authentication with SAS, even worse, I would have appr. 400 different SAS keys (20 storage accounts x 20 containers).

Now: On Azure, I created a new user, e. g. "backupuser@mycompany.com", which is a global reader - so no possibility to write/delete, which would satisfy the security issues. I registered my application as a Windows application.

However, despite reading and trying out so many ways, I was not able to figure out how my console application can automatically log in through e. g. Azure Active Directory (password) with the username + password of backupuser@mycompany.com. It would also be important to store username/password e. g. in appsettings.json).

Can you provide .NET Core C# code how I can a) login and b) list all blobs in one storage account >> container?

Thanks so much!!

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your need, I suggest you use Azure AD auth to access Azure Blob. If you use the way, we need to assgin `Storage Blob Data Reader` to the user or service principal. After that, the user or service principal has permission to list containers and blobs. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-reader) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

For example

1. Create a service principal and assign `Storage Blob Data Reader` role to the sp

```
az login

# assign role at the description level the sp can manage all storage account in the subscription
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "ManageStorage" --role "Storage Blob Data Reader"
```

[image]

2. Set environmental variables

```
setx AZURE_CLIENT_ID <your-clientID>

setx AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET <your-clientSecret>

setx AZURE_TENANT_ID <your-tenantId>
```

3. Application

a. sdk

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.4.4" />
```

b. Code

```
            string accountName = "jimtestdiag417";
            string url = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", accountName);
            var account = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(url), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            string containerContinuationToken = null;
            int pageSizeHint = 5; //The size of Page<T>s that should be requested 
            // list conatnies in the storage account
            do
            {
                var containerResultSegment = account.GetBlobContainersAsync().AsPages(containerContinuationToken, pageSizeHint);
                await foreach (Page<BlobContainerItem> containerPage in containerResultSegment) {

                    foreach (var container in containerPage.Values) {

                        Console.WriteLine( string.Format("The blobs in the container {0} are as follows ", container.Name));
                        string blobContinuationToken = null;
                        // list blobs in the container
                        do
                        {

                            var blobResultSegment = account.GetBlobContainerClient(container.Name).GetBlobsAsync().AsPages(blobContinuationToken, pageSizeHint);
                            await foreach (Page<BlobItem> blobPage in blobResultSegment)
                            {

                                foreach (var blob in blobPage.Values)
                                {
                                       Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
                                    
                                }

                            }
                        } while (blobContinuationToken != null);

                       
                    }
                }
            } while (containerContinuationToken != null);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I will try this out! Is there a way to pass the environment variables in the code to authenticate without setting them in windows?

Comment: @SmartInMedia Yes, you can do that. You can change `DefaultAzureCredential` as `ClientSecretCredential` then you set these settings in your code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @SmartInMedia Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?